# Generate unused model classes with openapi

Tags: java, rest, openapi, dto

OpenApi genereates only used DTO-s in my project. How can I generate unused DTO-s?
E.g.: I have the following configuration. My problem is that BDto is not generated.

```
myMethod:
  get:
    operationId: myMethod
    parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
    responses:
      '200':
        description: OK
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: array
              items:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ADto'
      default:
        $ref: '../common/response.yaml#/components/responses/UnexpectedError'
    tags:
      - my-controller
components:
  schemas:
    ADto:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
      discriminator:
        propertyName: discriminator

    BDto:
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ADto'
        - type: object
          properties:
            value:
              type: number
              format: double
```